# fetching all rows in my mysql database using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

Guys i have a problem actually my php code is correct but i dont know why it display undefined into my client side script. Could somebody help me

here is my api.php this is where i put my php

```
<?php 
 $dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "orms") or die("Server not  available" . mysql_error());
 $data = array();
 $result = mysqli_query($dbcon,"SELECT * FROM cottages") or die(mysqli_error());            //query
//$array = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {
  $data[] = $row;
 }
 echo json_encode( $data )                          //fetch result    
?>
```

here is my client.php code

```
   <?php 
     $dbcon = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "orms") or die("Server not available" . mysql_error());
 ?>
<html>
 <head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">    </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2> Client example </h2>
 <h3>Output: </h3>
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

  $(function () 
  {
$.ajax({                                      
url: 'api.php', data: "POST", dataType: 'json',  success: function(rows)        
 {
   for (var i in rows)
   {
  var row = rows[i];          

  var cot_id = row[0];
  var image = row[1];
  $('#output').append("<b>cottage: </b>"+cot_id+"<b> image: </b>"+image)
              .append("<hr />");
      } 
     } 
       });

    }); 
  </script>

       </body>
         </html>
```

Thanks for your help in advance..

Comment: The problem is data: "POST" use type: "POST"

Comment: Since the script doesn't read parameters, it doesn't matter whether he uses `GET` or `POST`.

Comment: hello i did it but same error occured.. undefined

Comment: `mysql_error()` wont work with `mysqli_connect` different drivers. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: Hi Chris error still occured. with your suggestion to change it to mysqli_error();

Comment: show us your json response

Comment: you are not selecting the items from the json properly

Comment: hi Madalin please refer to above code i paste the code for jason response I tried it to access the api.php and it displays the values on the database. Now my problem is i cant get the values on the client side.

Comment: Why are you connecting to the database in `client.php` when you don't perform any database queries there?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
Read it.

Comment: forget semi column in this line echo json_encode( $data );

Comment: show us the echo of your json_encode

Answer (score 1):

You're using `mysqli_fetch_assoc`, so the row will be an associative array, which turns into a Javascript object. But in the Javascript code you're accessing `row` as if it's an array, not an object. You need to use the column names:

```
var cot_id = row.cot_id;
var image = row.image;
```

(I'm just guessing the column names, because you used `SELECT *` so I can't see the actual names in your table.)

Comment: Hi barmar! very thanks to your help.. this is now working. but wait theres more ill be trying to include javascript on this one :) wait a minute ill post it in a while.